# how to input and out put in a binary file in with changing cursor in c++?

Tags: c++, hash

i have a problem with write in file and read it back.when i open file in append mode.
and when i change the cursor of file it just mix up and dont work.
how can i write in file in hash position and read it back with hash with Order(1)?
thx for helping by the way.

```
struct student{
    int id;
    char name[20];
}st;

int hashing(char word[20])
{
        int hash;
        int sum=0;
        int z;

    sum += (int)word[0];
    sum += (int)word[1];
    z=(sum)%1000;
    hash=z*sizeof(student);

    return hash;
}
void main()
{
fstream op("d://ttest.txt",ios::app | ios::binary);
if(!op)
{
    cout<<endl<<"cant open file :D in write !!!!!!:"<<endl;
    getch();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cin>>st.id>>st.name;

    op.seekp(hashing(st.name),ios::beg);
    op.write((char *)&st,sizeof(student));
}
op.close();
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

fstream op2("d://ttest.txt",ios::in | ios::binary);
if(!op2)
{
    cout<<endl<<"cant open file :D in write !!!!!!:"<<endl;
    getch();
}
char temp[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    st.id=0;
    cin>>temp;
    op2.seekp(hashing(temp),ios::beg);
    op2.read((char *)&st,sizeof(student));
    cout<<st.id<<"  "<<st.name<<endl;

    //op.seekp(hashing(st.name),ios::beg);

}
op2.close();
getch();
}
```

Comment: Don't open in append mode `std::app` open in read and write mode `std::ios::in|std::ios::out`.

Comment: i have to do that caz i want to keep my info in file for next time.

Comment: I think you will have to create the file first and make it large enough.

Comment: first of all thx for helping. what do u mean by that? i have to store my info in a record that my hash show. and after that i have to restore that info by hash again. so i have to change files's cursor. so i can have achievement with Order(1)

Comment: Your hash function looks like it addresses 1000 records. So you could try to open your file for read/write. If that fails create a new file by opening for append and writing 1000 blank records. Then re-open the file in read/write again and carry on as normal.

Comment: if i open file as write then i will use my info. but my problem is changing the file's cursor. if i dont change file cursor it work correctly but whenever i do that it goes wrong and i dont know why.

Comment: You can't move your cursor to a position in a file that is not large enough, so first you have to make the file large enough to contain all your records (up to 1000).

Comment: aha. i get it so how can i make my file large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might detect if the database file is initialized and if not, do the initialization:

```
struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
};

int main()
{
    const std::string filename = "database.txt";

    std::fstream fs;

    // try to open the file
    fs.open(filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

    if(!fs)
    {
        // Assume it needs initializing - create new file
        std::cout << "Initializing database: " << filename << '\n';

        student s;
        s.id = -1; // empty
        s.name[0] = '\0';

        fs.clear();
        fs.open(filename, std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);

        if(!fs)
        {
            // can't recover from this
            std::cout << "ERROR: initializing database: " << filename << '\n';
            return 1;
        }

        // write 1000 empty student records
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            fs.write((char*) &s, sizeof(s));

        fs.close();

        // try again
        fs.open(filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    }

    if(!fs) // still not working?
    {
        // not just an initialization issue, must abort
        std::cout << "ERROR: opening database: " << filename << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    // Database open and ready for business ...

}
```